# Overwrite Flash Window.close event with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, overwrite

I am facing a strange issue and need immediate help if possible. I have a HTML page where I have Flash Video Embedded. It also have video controller in same swf. That controller has a button which closes browser window on click. I want to overwrite it some way ( either with JavaScript/ Jquery if possible) and want to run my own function at same time.

If you need any other detail here I will be happy to add here.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: seems like you only have `onbeforeunload` option here

Comment: OK Cherniv,
I tried onbeforeunload function but could not get an idea like how I stop closing window only on that particular button click of flash. onbeforeunload also behaves positively when I click close button of browser or refresh the page.

Comment: Generally, to change the behavior of Flash code, you need to change the Flash code itself. Flash and Javascript can communicate w/each other through Flash's `ExternalInterface` class, but you have to write code in both Flash and Javascript to support this.